# How to overwrite specific partitions in spark/BigQuery/GCP

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark

How to overwrite specific partitions in spark/BigQuery/GCP?

I user this Code,

```
 df.write  \
          .format("bigquery") \
          .mode("overwrite") \
          .option("table",bq_path) \
          .option("temporaryGcsBucket",GCS_BUCKET) \
          .option("partitionField",'partition_date') \
          .save()
```

but when batch is Executed, the existing data is deleted.

Please Refer this Image. -->>
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2ygv.png)

Comment: " when batch is Executed, the existing data is deleted."  , "How to overwrite specific partitions" . this is the goal of overwritting ... overwrite replace olf data with the ew one. maybe you looking for append mode ?
if you want to overwrite only specific partition, you should make a new dataset and use partitionBy()

Comment: I think the meaning is wrong because I can't speak English well.

“When the batch is executed, the existing data is deleted.” Meaning, if I put the data on August 5th, all data will disappear except for August 5th, which I just put in.

The meaning of "How to overwrite specific partitions" means that if I put August 5th data into the dataset that has August 5th and August 4th data, only the August 5th data will be overwritten.

Comment: I think you can try setting Spark option `spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic`. Check here https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-dynamic-partition-inserts.html

Comment: Firstly, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector), you should specify `partitionType` when using `partitionField`. Could you specify it? In addition, you could t you use `.option("datePartition", "YYYYMMDD") .save("table")` instead of `.option("partitionField",'partition_date') .save()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that:

```
df.write.format('bigquery') \
        .option("datePartition", "20220810").mode("overwrite") \
        .option("partitionField", "processed_date") \
        .option('table', "YOUR_TABLE") \
        .save()
```